# Equations of tangent lines

Tags: calculus

f(x)= 1/(3-2x); P(-1,1/5)

The question asked me to do it in a certain way.
m=lim h approaches 0 f(x+h)-f(x)/h

Now I did it like this and decided to use make the function over 1. (ie. 3-2(x+h))^-1.

I did this and just factored and simplified. I got -1/2. Is that correct?

=(3-2(x+h))^-1 - (3-2(-1))^-1 x (1/h)

=(3-2x-2h)^-1- (5)^-1 x(1/h)

=(3-2x-2h+5)^-1

=-1/2

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Notice $f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.$ So you just compute the function $f'(x)=(\frac{1}{3-2x})'$ at point $(-1, \frac15)$.

The correct answer should be $\frac{2}{(3-2x)^2}\big|_{x=-1}=\frac{2}{25}$.

May it helps!